# How to mock application path when unit testing Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I am testing code in a MVC HTML helper that throws an error when trying to get the application path:

```
//appropriate code that uses System.IO.Path to get directory that results in:
string path = "~\\Views\\directory\\subdirectory\\fileName.cshtml";
htmlHelper.Partial(path, model, viewData); //exception thrown here
```

The exception that is thrown is

> System.Web.HttpException: The application relative virtual path '~/Views/directory/subdirectory/fileName.cshtml' cannot be made absolute, because the path to the application is not known.

Following the advice of [How to resolve issue with image path when testing HtmlHelper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425133/how-to-resolve-issue-with-image-path-when-testing-htmlhelper/3428418#3428418)
I have faked (using Moq):

- `Request.Url` to return a string
- `Request.RawUrl` to return a string
- `Request.ApplicationPath` to return a string
- `Request.ServerVariables` to return a null NameValueCollection
- `Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(string virtualPath)` to return a string

What else is needed to be able to allow this code to run in the context of a unit test run?
Or
What other approach should I be taking to render a Partial view on a dynamically built string?

Comment: @StuperUser It isn't a full answer to your question but if you set your Mocks to be created as `new Mock<I....>(MockBehavior.Strict)` you will get ASP.NET MVC and Moq to tell you what you need - you will get exceptions thrown for setups you haven't implemented.

Comment: Thanks @Ciaran, that's useful to know, but it appears I've mocked everything necessary for `MockBehavior.Strict` to allow me to run the test to line throwing the exception.

Comment: I typically don't unit test the rendering process. What will you consider a "pass" on this unit test?

Comment: The test is for the building of that path, but I suppose that that should be placed in a helper class and tested there.

Comment: @Hector, if you would like reputation for a question that prompted some good rubber ducking (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking), please answer below and you'll get an upvote and an accepted answer.

Comment: Funny thing is that I was called a duck in a totally different context just this weekend :) I am glad I was able to help.

Comment: You can try the solution here: http://blog.jardalu.com/2013/4/23/httprequest_mappath_vs_httpserverutility_mappath

Comment: @arni that blog post URL is returning 404

Comment: @StuperUser I copied archived blog contents as a separate answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As an alternative to mocking built-in .net classes, you can

```
public interface IPathProvider
{
    string GetAbsolutePath(string path);
}

public class PathProvider : IPathProvider
{
    private readonly HttpServerUtilityBase _server;

    public PathProvider(HttpServerUtilityBase server)
    {
        _server = server;
    }

    public string GetAbsolutePath(string path)
    {
        return _server.MapPath(path);
    }
}
```

Use the above class to get absolute paths.

And for For unit testing you can mock and inject an implementation of IPathProvider that would work in the unit testing environment.

--UPDATED CODE

Comment: Is `DefaultPathProvider` a class in the MVC library that already implements `IPathProvider`?

Comment: no. its our own.  It is just a wrapper over the built-in .net functionality.  The advantage here is we do not have to mock the whole request stack for unit testing. just the IPathProvider.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, I ran up against the same error and followed it through the `System.Web` source to find it occurs because `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPathObject` is null.

This is an immutable property on the HttpRuntime singleton, initialized as follows:

```
Thread.GetDomain().GetData(key) as String
```

where key is `".appVPath"`. i.e. it comes from the AppDomain. It might be possible to spoof it with:

```
Thread.GetDomain().SetData(key, myAbsolutePath)
```

But honestly the approach in the accepted answer sounds much better than mucking around with the AppDomain.

Comment: You would also need to set  ".appDomain":
`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(".appDomain", "*");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(".appVPath", "/appbase");`

Comment: @arni Your comment and this answer worked right off the bat while I was unit-testing RazorEngine rendering which required resolving virtual paths!

Answer (score 4):

I'm including a solution from a blog post, which is no longer available (http://blog.jardalu.com/2013/4/23/httprequest_mappath_vs_httpserverutility_mappath)

Complete code: http://pastebin.com/ar05Ze7p

> Ratna (http://ratnazone.com) code uses "HttpServerUtility.MapPath" for
>   mapping virtual paths to physical file path. This particular code has
>   worked very well for the product. In our latest iteration, we are
>   replacing HttpServerUtility.MapPath with HttpRequest.MapPath.
>
> Under the hoods, HttpServerUtility.MapPath and HttpRequest.MapPath are
>   the same code and will result in the same mapping. Both of these
>   methods are problematic when it comes to unit testing.
>
> Search for "server.mappath null reference" in your favourite search
>   engine. You are going to get over 10,000 hits. Almost all of these
>   hits are because test code calls HttpContext.Current and
>   HttpServerUtility.MapPath. When the ASP.NET code is executed without
>   HTTP,  HttpContext.Current will be null.
>
> This issue (HttpContext.Current is null) can be solved very easily by
>   creating a HttpWorkerRequest and intializing HttpContext.Current with
>   that. Here is the code to do that -
>
> ```
> string appPhysicalDir = @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot";
> string appVirtualDir = "/";
>
> SimpleWorkerRequest request = new SimpleWorkerRequest(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, "/", null, new StringWriter());
> HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request);
> ```
>
> With that simple code in unit test, HttpContext.Current is
>   initialized. Infact, if you notice, HttpContext.Current.Server
>   (HttpServerUtility) will also be intiailzed. However, the moment, the
>   code tries to use Server.MapPath, the following exception will get
>   thrown.
>
> ```
> System.ArgumentNullException occurred
>   HResult=-2147467261
>   Message=Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: path
>   Source=mscorlib
>   ParamName=path
>   StackTrace:
>        at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean checkAdditional)
>   InnerException: 
>             HttpContext.Current = context;
> ```
>
> Infact, if the code uses HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath, it is
>   going to get the same exception. If the code uses Request.MapPath, the
>   issue can be resolved in the unit test easily. The following code in
>   unit test shows how.
>
> ```
> string appPhysicalDir = @"c:\inetpub\wwwroot";
> string appVirtualDir = "/";
>
> SimpleWorkerRequest request = new SimpleWorkerRequest(appVirtualDir, appPhysicalDir, "/", null, new StringWriter());
> FieldInfo fInfo = request.GetType().GetField("_hasRuntimeInfo", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
> fInfo.SetValue(request, true);
> HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request);
> ```
>
> In the above code, the request worker will be able to resolve the map
>   path. This is not enough though, because HttpRequest does not have the
>   HostingEnvironment set (which resolves MapPath). Unfortunately,
>   creating a HostingEnvironment is not trivial. So for unit-test, a
>   "mock host" that just provides the MapPath functionality is created.
>   Again, this MockHost hacks lot of internal code. Here is the
>   pseudo-code for the mock host. Complete code can be downloaded here:
>   http://pastebin.com/ar05Ze7p
>
> ```
> public MockHost(physicalDirectory, virtualDirectory){ ... }
> public void Setup()
> {
>    Create new HostingEnvironment
>    Set Call Context , mapping all sub directories as virtual directory
>    Initialize HttpRuntime's HostingEnvironment with the created one
> }
> ```
>
> With the above code when MapPath is called on HttpRequest by it should
>   be able to resolve the path.
>
> As a last step, in the unit test, add the following code -
>
> ```
> MockHost host = new MockHost(@"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\", "/");
> host.Setup();
> ```
>
> Since now a HostingEnvironment has been initialized, the test code
>   will be able to resolve virtual paths when
>   HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath method is called (along with
>   HostingEnvironment.MapPath and HttpServerUtility.MapPath).
>
> Download MockHost code here: http://pastebin.com/ar05Ze7p

Answer (score 2):

[Trying to make parts of ASP.NET happy with various types of tests](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/06/17/unit-testing-an-asp.net-virtualpathprovider.aspx/) seems, to me, to be quite fragile. And I am inclined to believe that the mocking route only works if you basically avoid using ASP.NET or MVC and, instead, write your own webserver from scratch.

Instead, just use [`ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.applicationhost.createapplicationhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a properly-initialized `AppDomain`. Then run your test code from within that domain using [`AppDomain.DoCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Web.Hosting;

public class AppDomainUnveiler : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public AppDomain GetAppDomain()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var appDomain = ((AppDomainUnveiler)ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost(
            typeof(AppDomainUnveiler),
            "/",
            Path.GetFullPath("../Path/To/WebAppRoot"))).GetAppDomain();
        try
        {
            appDomain.DoCallback(TestHarness);
        }
        finally
        {
            AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
        }
    }

    static void TestHarness()
    {
        //…
    }
}
```

Note: when trying this myself, my test runner code was in a separate assembly from the `WebAppRoot/bin` directory. This is an issue because, when `HostApplication.CreateApplicationHost` creates a new `AppDomain`, it sets its base directory to something like your `WebAppRoot` directory. Therefore, you *must* define `AppDomainUnveiler` in an assembly that is discoverable in the `WebAppRoot/bin` directory (so it must be in your webapp’s codebase and cannot be stored separately in a testing assembly, unfortunately). I suggest that if you want to be able to keep your test code in a separate assembly, you [subscribe to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373295/429091) in `AppDomainUnveiler`’s constructor. Once your testing assembly gets the `AppDomain` object, it can use [`AppDomain.SetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to pass along information about where to load the testing assembly. Then your `AssemblyResolve` subscriber can use [`AppDomain.GetData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to discover where to load the test assembly from. (I’m not sure, but the sort of objects you can `SetData`/`GetData` might be quite limited—I’ve just used `string`s myself to be safe). This is a bit annoying, but I think it is the best way to separate concerns in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This happens once you login to the application and you try to add any new url to the http context and trying to create SimpleWorkerRequest.

in my case i have an url to get the documents from remote server and added the url to http context and trying to authenticate the user and create the SimpleWorkerRequest.

Answer (score -1):

```
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var moqRequestContext = new Mock<RequestContext>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        request.SetupGet<RequestContext>(r => r.RequestContext).Returns(moqRequestContext.Object);
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("key1", "value1");
        moqRequestContext.Setup(r => r.RouteData).Returns(routeData);

        request.SetupGet(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns(PathProvider.GetAbsolutePath(""));

public interface IPathProvider
{
    string GetAbsolutePath(string path);
}

public class PathProvider : IPathProvider
{
     private readonly HttpServerUtilityBase _server;

     public PathProvider(HttpServerUtilityBase server)
     {
        _server = server;
     }

    public string GetAbsolutePath(string path)
    {
        return _server.MapPath(path);
    }
}
```